# Stable Identifier Conformance check

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

So I have the following code. According to [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns), this code shouldn't compile.

> A stable identifier pattern is a stable identifier r. The type of r must conform to the expected type of the pattern.

So why does it compile? The expected type is clearly `Bar`. Is this a bug in scalac?

```
object Test {
  def foo (b: Bar, a: A) = {
     b match {
       case `a` => println("A")
       case _ => println(":(")
     }
  }

  class A
  case class Bar(s: String)
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ Idea reports: `fruitless type test: a value of type Test.Bar cannot also be a Test.A`, although this does not lead to compile error

Comment: @Archeg IntelliJ Idea is sometimes wrong. The compiler doesn't even issue a warning

Comment: it looks to be correct in this case. It at least try to give you a clue that something is wrong. You clearly won't be able to make it execute first match. But if you change your case class into `case class Bar(s: String) extends A`, the warning is gone. I agree it'd have been nice if compiler could tell you that as well, but you cannot expect from compiler to be smart in all situations

Comment: @Archeg Actually, I am trying to improve pattern matching highlighting in Intellij Idea :)
So here, in my opinion, the compiler should issue an error and this code should be red. And I'm trying to figure out why this code compiles

Comment: Ah, I see :) Actually if you make your `class A` final, it will issue an error. It might have something to do with that. I keep thinking

Comment: @Archeg perhaps this is a bug in the compiler. If no one answers here, I will just file an issue on their bug tracker

Comment: You could ask in scala mailing list. They actually recommend to do that before creating a ticket. And leave this question hanging out - maybe somebody will get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (only for demo purposes, never do that again):

```
object Test {
  def foo (b: Bar, a: A) = {
    b match {
      case `a` => println("A")
      case _ => println(":(")
    }
  }

  class A
  case class Bar(s: String)
}

class B extends A {
  override def equals(other: Any) = true
}

Test.foo(Test.Bar("S"), new B)
```

I didn't expect for it to work, but it prints `A`

Class `B` can be defined anywhere, so compiler cannot be sure this case match is wrong, unless `A` is final